# Django Slugfield removing articles ('the', 'a', 'an', 'that')

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 1.10 and I have this setup:

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    date_completed = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In the admin, I have :

```
class ChapterAdmin (admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('title','slug', 'date_completed',)
    list_filter = ['title', 'date_completed']
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
```

I noticed that when I create a chapter with a title like "A boy and the pig", I get "boy-and-pig" as the slug. Django is stripping of the articles from my slug. Why is this so and what's the way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is this so?**

Well, that's the default behaviour of the [Slugfield,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/427102/what-is-a-slug-in-django) in Django.  Why is it like that?  Because generally, [it's been considered better for SEO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734970/better-seo-to-remove-stop-words-from-an-articles-url-slug).

*(I say considered, as the article linked mentions this might be dated thinking. The premise is that  articles and the like are usually considered [Stop Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words), the most common words in a language; they're so common that they are unhelpful for a search engine to index, as they feature in most, if not all titles.  )*

**What's the Way Around It?**

Firstly - why do you *want* to get around it?  What's the use case?

But if you're satisified you really want to do it, then it's quite simple:

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
would_be_slug = 'This is one of those rarest of things: A blog that uses article.'
slugify(would_be_slug)
>>>u'this-is-one-of-those-rarest-of-things-a-blog-that-uses-article'
```

[This answer has some great advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816307/how-to-create-a-unique-slug-in-django) on overriding standard fields and slugfields.

[There's also a nice package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autoslug) that will do this for you if you don't want to roll your own.

Comment: I've added a package that's relevant as well, but it's worth pointing out that you have slug and title both set to unique - presumably (but not necessarily, so this is more a headsup than anything), slug will be dependent on title, so that's a bit redundant.

Comment: you can combine pk + slugify(title) to keep the uniqueness.

Comment: I don't think showing pk is a good idea, we can add some random string.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own logic to filter specific words and articles out:

**List of Stop Words:**
Check out [this blog post about SEO and stop words](https://cseo.com/blog/seo-stop-words/). At the end of the page, you'll find [a list containing over hundreds of stop words](https://cseo.com/blog/seo-stop-words/#Bonus_SEO_stop_words_list_October_2022).

**Implementation:**

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  # new

      if not self.slug:
          # remove articles
          words_to_remove = ["the", "a", "an", "that", "this"] # etc.
          filtered_title = ""

          for word in self.title.split():
              if word not in words_to_remove:
                  filtered_title = filtered_title + " " + ''.join(str(word))
          # to keep uniqueness, combine the id with the title
          self.slug = slugify(str(self.pk) + "-" + filtered_title)
      return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```